# Django - Setting date as date input value

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to set a date as the value of a date input in a form. But, as your may have guessed, it's not working.

Here's what I have in my template:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="date" class="col-md-3 control-label">Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" value="{{placement.date}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the view that calls it as well as the Placement model:

```
class Placement(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    house = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    length = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

def view_placement(request, placement_id):
    school = School.objects.get(pk=request.session['school'])
    context = {'school':school}
    if request.session['utype'] == 'a':
        context['user'] = Administrator.objects.get(pk=request.session['user'])
        context['placement'] = Placement.objects.get(pk=placement_id)
        return render(request, 'workxp/admin/view_placement.html', context)
```

But it doesn't display the date. Just an empty date input...

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: you will have to give us your view.py code that calls this template.

Comment: can you upload your views [ and model details becoz here mostely we did like this means we will get the date so, please add that also

Comment: Added both model and view :)

Comment: @Pictraz Does the proposed solution work for you ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The HTML date should take the format YYYY-MM-DD. So you have to make a conversion using the `{{ value|date:"D d M Y" }}` command.

Your code will be:

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" value="{{placement.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}">
```

HTML documentation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value

Django date documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it out! Although the "Y M D" format didn't work, I changed it to the default format the HTML accepts by using "Y-m-d", and that put it in fine!

Comment: Good. strange about the exact format needed. the "Y M D" worked fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Noticed a small typo in the above answer -- the date format is in double quotes, inside of a set of double quotes. Should be single around 'Y-m-d' to work!

`<input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" value="{{placement.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}">`

should be:

`<input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" value="{{placement.date|date:'Y-m-d' }}">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use any date format.

Example, when used `{{ value|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}` in template:

```
from django.forms import DateField
from django.utils import formats
# need '%d.%m.%Y' instead of 'd.m.Y' from get_format()
dformat = ('.' + formats.get_format("SHORT_DATE_FORMAT", lang=request.LANGUAGE_CODE)).replace('.', '.%').replace('-', '-%').replace('/', '/%')[1:]
dfield = DateField(input_formats=(dformat,))
<date> = dfield.to_python(<string>)
```