# Django Changing Date Input Format

Tags: django

I have a simple booking form which is having a date input in a line like:

reservation.html

```
<textarea name="booking" class="form-control" id="reservation"
value="{{placement.date|date:'d/m/Y'}}"></textarea>
```

models.py

```
class Lib(models.Model):
    booking = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

My database postgresql based and also store date as in "date" format. I would love to change date-input like dd/mm/yyyy

I also tried to use placement.date|date type format in double quotes like:

```
<textarea name="booking" class="form-control" id="reservation"
value="{{placement.date|date:"d/m/Y"}}"></textarea>
```

But its still accept as mm/dd/YY. Is there any problem about my placement?  My forms.py kinda simple like:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Lib
from django.utils import formats

class LibForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lib
        fields = ['title','name','email','booking']
```

I searched on google and on stackoverflow and found something on  [Django - Setting date as date input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150639/django-setting-date-as-date-input-value/28151781)  and [django how to format date to DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641233/django-how-to-format-date-to-dd-mm-yyyy)  but i couldn't find anything that could help me. I have to seek help here as a last resort. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read this before 
?httpss://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_INPUT_FORMATS

Comment: My django ver is 3.1.4 it gives a "This document is for an insecure version of Django that is no longer supported. "

Comment: That's true, don't worry because input_formats have not change. Use this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_INPUT_FORMATS